# Php check if string contains multiple '?' or double '//'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an expression that checks if there is a `.` a `\` or a `%`:

```
$str = '/index.php?url=cont\roller//act%ion?id=5';
if(preg_match('/[.\\\\%]/', $str)){
    //do something
}
```

Now i'm trying to check if the string contains more than 1 `?` or if it has '//' double or more forward slashes one after another(as seen in the, obviously, wrong `str`).

Is there a way to check for all this in one expression?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get the string from? What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match_all('/[.\\\\%]|\/{2,}/', $str)){

}
```

carefull that your regex detects the `.` in `index.php`, you should simply remove the start of the string if it's `/index.php`

Runned it on console:

```
$str = '/index.php?url=cont\roller//act%ion?id=5';
preg_match_all('/[.\\\\%]|\/{2,}/', $str, $matchs);
var_dump($matchs);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "."
    [1]=>
    string(1) "\"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "//"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "%"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'`

Comment: 'g' is not used in php. I believe it's only a "regex101" thing.

Comment: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g'` now

Comment: it is used in many language but is not a standard flag since it consumes considerably more ressources. in php it translate in using `preg_match_all` method

Comment: @EmanuelOnes remove the `g` flag in the regex and use `preg_match_all`. edited my answer

Comment: i'm now using the if statement in the answer but it can't find `//` :(

Comment: @EmanuelOnes added the results using the example you provided

Comment: @N69S after i restarted the apache2 it started working but i still can't check if the `?` is more than once in the string :(

Comment: @EmanuelOnes you can do an `count(explode('?', $url)) > 2` if there  are two `?` or more, it will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after 1 day of trial and error here is the solution that i could come up with(part of it taken from @N69S answer):

```
if(preg_match_all('/[.\\\\%]|\/{2,}|(\?)(?=\?|.+\1)/', $str)){
    //do something
}
```

Pattern Explanation:

`[.\\\\%]` this part will match a `.` a `\` or a `%` it will return `1` if one of those characters is matched(`+1` for each occurance of either one of those characters)

`\/{2,}` this part will match `//` double or more than double forward consecutive slashes(`//` `///` `////` and so on)

`(\?)(?=\?|.+\1)` this part will check if `?` is more than once(duplicated) anywhere in that string

Comment: Did you run it?

Comment: @Toto thanks for noticing, i've edited it now you can run it.